# How do I get all of the secret endings?

Tags: you-are-jeff-bezos

According to the completion list for [*You Are Jeff Bezos*](https://direkris.itch.io/you-are-jeff-bezos), the game has three secret endings. How do I get these secret endings?

Comment: Thanks, I'm now spending Jeff's money instead of my actual work!

Answer (score 6):

border -> what else -> nasa -> double -> delete -> what else -> show twitter -> fund 10 animals -> secret end.
You can get to all 3 secret ends after depleting all money before getting caught, and the steps i provided above should get you to $0 before getting caught. Just go through the dialogues after these to get the 3 different secret ends which the first being a new billionaire, second a cat and third a robot.